# Compare quotient of two integers

Tags: integer, fixed-point

I am using fixed point code (i.e. only 16 and 32-bit integers).
Now I need to compare the quotient of two integers, which are very similar, e.g.

```
int result = 705/239;
int result2 = 720/235;
```

How could I tell which of the results would be larger by using only integers? Using floats is of course easier here, but not possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the divisors and multiply as in the following `compare` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// -ve if dividend1 ÷ divisor1 is less than dividend2 ÷ divisor2
// zero if dividend1 ÷ divisor1 is equal to dividend2 ÷ divisor2
// +ve if dividend1 ÷ divisor1 is greater than dividend2 ÷ divisor2
int compare(int dividend1, int divisor1, int dividend2, int divisor2) {
    int product1 = dividend1 * divisor2;
    int product2 = dividend2 * divisor1;
    return product1-product2;
}

void test(int dividend1, int divisor1, int dividend2, int divisor2) {
    int comparison = compare(dividend1, divisor1, dividend2, divisor2);
    char const* relation = (comparison < 0) ? "less than" : (comparison > 0) ? "greater than" : "equal to";
    printf("%d/%d is %s %d/%d.\n", dividend1, divisor1, relation, dividend2, divisor2);
}

int main() {
    test(705, 239, 720, 235);
}
```

Notes:

1. Neither quotient is larger if the ratios are equal.
2. This is different to comparing `dividend1/divisor1` and `divident2/divisor2` because integer division truncates the quotient. For example, the quotient is always zero when the divisor is greater than the dividend.
3. The result is undefined if any of the operations in `compare` overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Using basic maths:

```
int d1=705;
int d2=720;
int s1=239;
int s2=235;

int result1=d1/s1;
int result2=d2/s2;

if (d1*s2>d2*s1)
    result1 is bigger
else
   result2 is bigger
```